# Jquery submit function isn't working in combination with console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to check if a form was submitted, if it was submitted I want to log a value in the console for testing purposes.

Yet there's nothing logged inside the console and I can't find my issue.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Server</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="authPanel">
        <div id="authPanelTop">Server Login </br> <small id="subHeadline">Bitte authentifiziere deinen account</small></div>
        <form id="login">
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="inputField" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Passwort eingeben" />
            <button class="buttonStyle" type="submit">Authentifizieren</button>
        </form>
        </br><hr>
        <div id="authPanelTop">Oder registriere dich </br> <small id="subHeadline">Bitte gib deine daten ein um dich zu registrieren</small></div>
        <form>
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Vorname eingeben" />
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Nachname eingeben" />
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="inputField" type="password" placeholder="Passwort eingeben" />
            <input style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="inputField" type="text" placeholder="Email eingeben" />
            <button class="buttonStyle" type="submit">Registrieren</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#login').submit(function() {
          console.log('Form submitted');
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: `$('#login').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();
          console.log('Form submitted');
        });`

Comment: Do you have your console set to preserve logs when page navigates? By default when the page exits, the logs are cleared....

Comment: See the comment andrew left. You need to tell the HTML form not to do it's default submission (submit to itself).

Comment: This Submit is working. I'm getting the log messge. [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jinspeter/Lm9c4k7a/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the submission is made, the page gets navigated to another page. So unless you preserve the logs, the log gets cleared for every new page.

You can preserve the log using:

[image: preview]

If you want to stay in the same page, and do not want to navigate to the form's action, you can add:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

to the submit handler, which prevents the default event, and you can either submit it using AJAX or not submit at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#login').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Form submitted');
    });
</script>
```